# Error unexpected token: 'Trigger'

Tags: apex, trigger, error

I'm trying to write a trigger to populate information from a child record into the parent, and receiving the following error on line 13  unexpected token: 'Trigger'

```
trigger UpdateQuoteSOW on Statement_of_Work__c (after insert, after update) {

    Map<ID, SBQQ__Quote__c> parentQuote = new Map<ID, SBQQ__Quote__c>();
    List<Id> listIds = new List<Id>();

    for (Statement_of_Work__c childObj : Trigger.new) {
        listIds.add(childObj.Quote__c);
    }


    parentQuote = new Map<Id, SBQQ__Quote__c>([SELECT id, (SELECT ID, Background_Introduction__c FROM Statements_of_Work__r) FROM SBQQ__Quote__c WHERE ID IN :listIds]);

    for (Statement_of_Work__c SOW: Trigger:new){
        SBQQ__Quote__c myParentQuote = parentQuote.get(SOW.Quote__c);
        myParentQuote.Background_Introduction__c = SOW.Background_Introduction__c;
    }

    update parentQuote.values();
}
```

What I'm trying to do is copy rich Text information (Background_Introduction__c) into another rich text field (Background_Introduction__c) and keep all formatting and images as I can't do this with declarative functionality.

Any help would be much appreciated
Thank you!

Comment: Trigger.new not trigger:new, typos happen =P

Answer (score 4):

I think the error message is pretty straightforward and even tells you the line number.

most likely a typo on your part.

```
for (Statement_of_Work__c SOW: Trigger:new)
```

should be `Trigger.new`

Comment: no worries, welcome to SFSE by the way ;)